# Error: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Select Case dlg
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
            If TextBox12.Text = "" Then
                Dim a, b, c As Integer
                a = TextBox7.Text
                b = TextBox8.Text //my problem
                c = TextBox11.Text
                TextBox12.Text = a + b - c
            End If
            If TextBox6.Text = "" Then
                TextBox6.Text = "-"
            End If
```

I don't know how to fix this error:

> Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Comment: You can't convert an empty string to Int. You should check if the textbox is empty before trying to assign to the int variable

Comment: Turn **Option Strict On**. It will help in the long run. You need `Integer.TryParse(TextBox7.Text, a)`

Comment: Khakim, you should consider accepting one of the answers on this question. The answer that helped you would be the obvious choice to accept. It helps future readers of the post plus it helps you with gaining a little rep.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Integer.Parse:

```
Select Case dlg
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
            If TextBox12.Text = "" Then
                Dim a, b, c As Integer
                a = Integer.Parse(TextBox7.Text)
                b = Integer.Parse(TextBox8.Text) //my problem
                c = Integer.Parse(TextBox11.Text)
                TextBox12.Text = a + b - c
            End If
            If TextBox6.Text = "" Then
                TextBox6.Text = "-"
            End If
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `Int32.TryParse` instead, as i think(i'm not used to vb.net) this would also throw a exception if the string is empty

Answer (score 1):

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox8.Text) Then           
    b = Integer.Parse(TextBox8.Text)
End If
```

You can check if the textbox is empty or null and then use int parse.

Or you could use Pikoh's suggestion of using `Int32.TryParse`

[Int32.TryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Shouldn't be `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(..`?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx). The advantage of using `TryParse` is it won't throw an exception should the conversion fail:

```
Dim a As Integer = 0
Dim b As Integer = 0
Dim c As Integer = 0

Integer.TryParse(TextBox7.Text, a)
Integer.TryParse(TextBox8.Text, b)
Integer.TryParse(TextBox11.Text, c)

TextBox12.Text = (a + b - c).ToString()
```

You should also look at setting **[Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)**:

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.

This will help you write better code in the long run.