# Error when trying to do a search query 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Hello I am trying to do a search query on multiple tables however when I try to pass a integer from a textbox an error comes up

```
"System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.' FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format."
```

```
   Private Function GetData(ID As Integer) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim bsql As String = "SELECT * FROM BOOKING
                        INNER JOIN customers ON customers.customerID = booking.BCustomerID
                        WHERE customers.customerid = @ID;"
    Using cn As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SQLiteCommand(bsql, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", DbType.Int32).Value = ID

        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

    End Using
    Return dt

End Function
Private Sub IbtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ibtnBSearch.Click



    DgvBookings.DataSource = GetData(CInt(txtBsearchId.Text))


End Sub
```

Comment: Because _txtBsearchId.Text_ is empty? Did you check this condition (and even if it contains effectively an integer) before happily passing the Text to CInt (Hint: Int32.TryParse)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803276/error-conversion-from-string-to-type-integer-is-not-valid)

Answer (score 0):

To test if an entry by the user is a valid `Integer` your can use `Integer.TryParse()`. This method returns `True` or `False` so it can be used directly in an `If` statement. You provide 2 parameters. The first is a string to test and the second is a variable of type `Integer`. In addition to returning True/False, the method will fill the `Integer` variable with the converted value if the method is `True`.

```
Private Sub IbtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ibtnBSearch.Click
    Dim SearchID As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(txtBsearchId.Text, SearchID) Then
        DgvBookings.DataSource = GetData(SearchID)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in the Search box.")
    End If
End Sub
```